# javascript simple for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
var friends = ["Miha", "Artur", "Karen", "zollex"];
var len = friends.length;
var friend = 0;
var msg = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i <len; i++){ 
  friend = (i + 1);
  msg+= "Friend number " + friend + ":";
  msg+=friends[i] + "<br />";
  document.write(msg);
}
```

I have the following code written above. And it outpust following result:

Friend number 1:Miha
Friend number 1:Miha
Friend number 2:Artur
Friend number 1:Miha
Friend number 2:Artur
Friend number 3:Karen
Friend number 1:Miha
Friend number 2:Artur
Friend number 3:Karen
Friend number 4:zollex

While there should have been only 4 friends.Im really curious why the `document.write` repeats same name multiple times.

Comment: your out display function always call single time. You are showing it in your forloop..take it outside

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are builind up the string on every iteration with += and you are not resetting it on every iteration.

```
msg += "Friend number " + friend + ":";
    ^^
msg += friends[i] + "<br />";
    ^^
```

Move the `document.write` outside the for loop OR set `msg` back to empty on every iteration.

```
var friends = ["Miha", "Artur", "Karen", "zollex"];
var len = friends.length;
var friend = 0;
var msg = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i <len; i++){ 
  friend = (i + 1);
  msg += "Friend number " + friend + ":";
  msg += friends[i] + "<br />";
}
document.write(msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i <len; i++){ 
  msg = '';
  friend = (i + 1);
  msg+= "Friend number " + friend + ":";
  msg+=friends[i] + "<br />";
  document.write(msg);
}
```

you are overwriting the msg variable on each loop, while you should clear it at each one!

Comment: Probably because your first version was jibberish and wrong.

Comment: I just failed a copy past, there's no need to downvote 5 secondes after someone posts an answer ;)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That is how it works and you can see people removed the downvotes once you fixed it. (You are lucky they hung around to remove the votes)

Comment: true I could see it this way too. :)